# error installing skmultilearn.problem_transform package

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-multilearn

The error I get is :

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
skmultilearn.problem_transform (from versions: ) 
No matching distribution found for skmultilearn.problem_transform
```

Answer (score 9):

Try `pip install scikit-multilearn`